# Is the 'explicit' keyword necessary and/or recommended for WinRT classes?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

When constructing a type in WinRT, does the `explicit` keyword have the same functionality and value as it does for standard C++ types? Ie. does WinRT ref types support the implicit same conversion as standard C++ types?

```
#pragma once

#include <collection.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace Platform;

namespace RuntimeComponent2
{
    public ref class Class1 sealed
    {
    public:
        explicit Class1(Platform::String^ foo); // does the 'explicit' keyword here have any value?
    private: 
         Platform::String^ m_foo;
    };

    Class1::Class1(Platform::String^ foo)
        : m_foo(foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in C++/CX, but AFAIK ref classes can only be instantiated vía `ref new`. Implicit conversions otoh can only occur by creating objects which (conceptually) reside on the stack.

So if I am right about the `ref new`, implicit conversion cannot occur with `ref class` objects and the `explicit` keyword has no use in their constructors (and C++11 conversion operators).

Comment: Specifically, ctors (non default) in C++/CX are turned into class factory methods, so the syntax lies quite a bit. They aren't really ctors.